# Django Rest Swagger: 'APIGroupAction' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am getting this issue while integrating `django-rest-swagger==2.1.2` with existing project `djangorestframework==3.5.3` .

I tried using quickstart with class based views which mention serializer_class in them:

```
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Pastebin API')
```

then, I tried with few futhis way as wellnction based views as:

`@api_view()
@renderer_classes([SwaggerUIRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer])
def schema_view(request):
generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(title='Pastebin API')
return response.Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))`

In both cases, it is giving the same error as :
'APIGroupAction' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.
Edit: 'APIGroupAction' is a class based view.

Comment: What is `APIGroupAction`? Can you add it?

Comment: Can you add the snippet of `APIGroupAction` class?

Comment: Hi thanks  for your comment, I solved it by: 
1- downgrading to django-rest-swagger==2.1.1
2- adding serializer to the missing view which I oversaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Django rest framework` > 3.0 , It is compulsory to have serializer for any View.
In your case `APIGroupAction` is view and It has not provided any serializer . so ,

Make one serializer for `APIGroupAction` eg.`APIGroupActionserializer`  and

In `APIGroupAction` write this line
`serializer_class = APIGroupActionserializer`

Comment: I have mentioned this in the question, that I have already tried doing this.

Comment: Hi yes I was integrating it into existing project , so 'APIGroupAction' this class existed at 2 places in the code, which I oversaw